# Running server locally hits 404

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting a server `net::ERR_ABORTED 404` (Not Found when running this on my node server. I am new to working with backend, so hoping someone can provide advice on why I am receiving this error?

```
app.use(express.static("HomePage"));

app.get('/?url', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const data = await fetchSomeData();
    return res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message : "Oops." });
  }
});
```

Comment: `404` means `Not Found`: what URL do you try to access?

Comment: @pzaenger I want to access my homepage, so / , and then return results on that page, so using querey to create a /url which would be whatever url is searched on the client side

Comment: Then, `'/?url'` makes not that much sense, give `*` a try. Or maybe something like `app.use(async (req, res) => { ... });`